# Android EditText error message popup text not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I'm having an issue in my app where the error popup on EditTexts shows but the text is not visible.
It looks something like this:

[image: EditText error message]

This happens with all the `EditText`s in my app.
Here's an example layout XML

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.onboarding.profile.OnboardingUserProfileActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shapes_background" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/user_profile_placeholder"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/cameraImageButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstnameTvLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorVeryLightGray"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstnameTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_firstname"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@id/lastnameTv"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@id/lastnameTv"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/lastnameTvLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorVeryLightGray"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastnameTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_lastname"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@id/usernameTv"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@id/usernameTv"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/usernameTvLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorVeryLightGray"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/usernameTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
                    android:imeActionId="6"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@id/nextBtn"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@id/nextBtn"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PrimaryButton"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/form"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
  <style name="AppTheme.WhiteEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorVeryLightGray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Setting error in the activity using `firstnameTv.error = "This field can not be empty"` (Kotlin)

Comment: For wich component are you setting the error message? TextInputLayout or TextInputLayout?

Comment: Your layout appears incomplete; it seems to be wrapped in a ConstraintLayout but I don’t see any constraints; did you purposely remove them? Also how/who is setting the error?

Comment: Error is being set on the TextInputEditText using setError. I'll update the question to post the full layout. But not sure its layout dependent since all the EditTexts in my app have this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use 
**`style="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText"`**

Instead of **`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent"`**

> Now question is why need to use **`style`** Instead of **`android:theme`**

When you use **`style`**  it apply will apply only to that `view`

and When you use **`android:theme`**  it apply will apply `view` as well as all of its `children`.

Read more about [**`What is the difference between style and android:theme attributes?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843867/what-is-the-difference-between-style-and-androidtheme-attributes)

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@color/colorNavBar"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/cameraImageButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstnameTvLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorVeryLightGray"
                style="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstnameTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="First Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@id/lastnameTv"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@id/lastnameTv"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/lastnameTvLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorVeryLightGray"
                style="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastnameTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Last Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@id/usernameTv"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@id/usernameTv"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/usernameTvLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorVeryLightGray"
                style="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/usernameTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="user Name"
                    android:imeActionId="6"
                    android:imeActionLabel="AB"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@id/nextBtn"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@id/nextBtn"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/form"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> style

```
<style name="AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.WhiteEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorVeryLightGray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the error in TextInputLayout, NOT in TextInputEditText

```
firstnameTvLayout.setError("Error goes here");
```

Also make sure you have done

```
firstnameTvLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
```

See the documentation here for more details https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use `style` instead of `android:theme`**. If you set `android:theme` to a view group, its children (error pop-up, in this case) will use the same style.

#### Your code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ....
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent"
    ....>
```

#### Change it to

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ....
    style="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent"
    ....>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textInputLayout.setErrorEnable(true);
```