# Android TextInputEditText/TextInputLayout cuts off error message

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

When setting a long error message on a TextInputEditText, it cuts it in two lines, but only one line is displayed:

[image]

Any way to solve this? I'm ok with two or multi lines, but they should be displayed properly.

Comment: Can you share the code ..  i would like to try it out.

Comment: See below, I solved it, but thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52693328/7666442

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out the problem was the styling... If you do something like:

```
<style name="V2NormalInput" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
....
</style>
```

And apply that to a TextInputEditText it'll clip the error message...

So the solution was simply to remove the parent:

```
<style name="V2NormalInput">
....
</style>
```

Now it works.

Comment: Hey @breakline removing parent doesn't affect the layout?

Comment: Seems okay to me at the moment